# Django - Optional cleaner GET parameters in URL?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, get, django-urls

I'm trying to set up an object filter bar on my template. This consists of a few `<select>` dropdowns. I plan on then sending those back to my view by reloading the URL but with GET requests.

So my question has two parts:

1. Is there a way to make GET parameters optional with Django? For example, can I have mysite.com which gives me the default view and also mysite.com/name/age which filters by name and age parameters?
2. As per the above example. Say I want to filter by 5 or 6 parameters, or maybe miss some out. How do I do that so I'm not having a giant URL like mysite.come/name/age/occupation/birthday/bankbalance?

EDIT: For further clarification, I'd like to know if I can also have these parameters out of order, so it wouldn't always need to be name before age, etc. So I could have age/occupation/name for example.

Comment: GET parameters are different from URL parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel already mentionned in a comment, you seem to be confusing Django's url params and HTTP "GET" params.

The firsts are the "dynamic" parts in a Django url pattern definition (your `urls.py` file), and are actually extracted from the "path" part of the url (the "/path/to/someresource" part). This is internal Django stuff.

The seconds are part of the HTTP spec and are the parts that goes after the "?" in an url, ie  in "/path/to/someresource?foo=bar&baaz=quux", the GET params are "foo=bar" and "baaz=quux". This part - named the "query string" - is NOT used by Django's url patterns (which only work on the "path" part). It's accessible in the view from `request.GET`, then it's up to the view to do something with it or ignore it totally.

From a semantic POV, for filters on listing view, you want HTTP GET params, not url params (you are still accessing the same resource, not a different one). From a practical POV, you ALSO want HTTP GET params, as it's much simpler to handle than trying to use urlpatterns for this:

```
def myview(request):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    param1 = request.GET.get("param1", None)
    if param1:
        queryset = queryset.filter(somefield=param1)
    param2 = request.GET.get("param2", None)
    if param2:
        queryset = queryset.filter(otherfield=param2)
    # etc
    return render(request, "mytemplate.html", {"objects": queryset})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This really clears things up for me. Would you be able to clarify this statement in your answer: "From a practical POV, you ALSO want HTTP GET params"? I'm not sure I understand what you mean there

Comment: @Cm1695 I mean that for what you're trying to do, it's __much__ easier to use HTTP GET params than trying to embed them in the url's path and handle them with Django's url patterns. And when I say "much easier", I'm talking orders (plural) of magnitude, really.

Comment: Ah got it. Yeah now that I understand that difference I can see what you mean there

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it to the request as an query param so your url would look like

```
path('api/your-url', YourView.as_view(), name='your-view')
```

Your view file would look like

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    params = request.GET.get('exampleParam')
    #do something with params
```

All the view will work and the delete will delete based off whats in the url so for example if the url is

```
domain.com/api/url?exampleParam=1
```

Your delete view would be able to get it now without having to add a new view